# How to send binary file multipart/form-data using post Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have tried to send a binary file with additional fields using post method and multipart/form-data.

```
load() {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.data.binary);
    formData.append('reasons', this.form.get('reasons').value);

    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
        key: userKey,
    });

    const options = { headers: headers };

    this.http
        .post(`/api/Controller`, formData, options)
        .pipe(catchError(this.handleError))
        .subscribe(
            () => {
                alert('Success');
            },
            (error) => {
                alert(error.Message || 'Error');
            },
        );
}
```

Where `this.data.binary` is:

```
 try {
            const input = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
            const reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = () => {
                this.data.binary = reader.result;
            };
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(input.files[0]);
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e);
        }
```

In Chrome headers I see this data after submit:

**FormData**

```
  file: [object ArrayBuffer]
  reasons: text
```

How to send file as binary correct?

I have trird also this:

```
   formData.append('file', new Blob(this.data.binary));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't use the FileReader to read it as binary.
Just use the FormData and append it directly

```
const formData = new FormData()
formData.append('file', input.files[0])
```

beside, readAsBinaryString is a bad practices and should use arrayBuffer instead when dealing with binary

I would also suggest that you do something like `new FormData(formElement)` so that you don't have to append/set every single field that is needed.